# Smartest way to send GPS data from Android to Django

Tags: android, python, json, django, gps

I'm writing an android app that uses GPS. It sends the NMEA string in a JSON object back to a django app I've already written (for similar use with an arduino+GPS). In order to send the data, I'm using sockets (the socket connection is on a intentservice, the gps code on a regular service).

The sockets are handled by the python tornado webserver, which receives the json object and adds the data to a PostGIS database with the appropriate django model, while still letting me browse the app from a browser like you would normally.

These are both my first android and django apps and I'm looking to improve them as well as my own coding/knolwedge of both platforms.

I'm just wondering if there are better, smarter ways of accomplishing these tasks.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but it doesn't sound like you have a specific problem.  SO works best for resolving issues.  If what you have works, what are you looking to improve?

Comment: The socket part I suppose. It seems like having Tornado in a django project just for sockets seems like such a hack, rather than a "proper" solution.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using websockets? Usual way (for handling / logging incoming data) would be to have a normal view, process POST data from the request and log it to the db.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this third party rest framework (DRF): http://www.django-rest-framework.org

Gives you a django side solution out of the box. There are others (tasty-py) but in my opinion DRF is the best there is.

No need to do anything with sockets i suppose...

Comment: Given that I already have the socket code, what advantages will using the REST framwork offer me over sockets?

For context, I'm pushing JSON objects through a socket to the server. In the JSON object theres a device ID, a nmea string and a few other odds and ends.

Comment: A lot, did you have a look at it? E. G. Write an api in 3 lines of code... have a browsable api as an extra (very usefull for testing) And it's very complete: all serializers,  api views ... and so on.

Comment: By the way: you asked for 'the smartest way' wrijving things that are already available in a this party packages that is maintained very actively ( even supported hugely by crowdfunding) does not seem the smartest way to me?